# Jquery onload duplicates results

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm having an issue with PHP `include` and jQuery `onload` when the `<li>` content refreshes `onload` it duplicates the results that returned from the `include function`

My code as below:

```
<li   class="dropdown">  
<a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" ><img src="style/img/notification.png" /></a>
<ul style="overflow:sauto; width:300px; overflow:auto;" class="dropdown-menu">
<?php  include("inc/noti_refresh.php"); ?>              
</ul>
</li>
```

here is my `noti_refresh.php`:

```
    <?php  include("configa.php");
$me = $_SESSION['username'];
$noti = mysql_query("select * from notification where to_user = '$me' order by id DESC   ");
//$rown = mysql_num_rows($noti);
while ($notime = mysql_fetch_array($noti)){
$me = $notime['to_user'];
$you = $notime['from_user'];
$p_id = $notime['p_id'];
$type = $notime['type'];
$uimage = mysql_query("select * from users where username = '$you'");
$uname = mysql_fetch_assoc($uimage);
$myimage = $uname['img'];
//if( $rown !=0) {
?>
<li class="ref"><a href="photo/<?php echo $p_id; ?>"><img src="users/<?php echo $myimage; ?>" style="height:32px; width:32;" /> <?php echo $you; ?> Has <?php echo  $type; ?> Your Image </a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
 <?php }?>
```

and this is my jQuery function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Load_external_content()
{

  $('.ref').load('inc/noti_refresh.php').hide().fadeIn(3000);

}
setInterval('Load_external_content()', 10000);
</script>
```

Now whenever the `<li class="ref">` is refreshed, the results will show duplicated.

Could anyone help?

Comment: is is because your `noti_refresh.php` appends a `<li class="ref">` element on every refresh so after the second load there be two `<li class="ref">` elements

Comment: I dont get it, by what I understand of your code what is going to happens is every 10 secs the .ref will be reloaded, but always with the same content because you are using a session to get the notifications by the user `$me = $_SESSION['username'];`
Oh, if you really wana do that, just take off the `<?php  include("inc/noti_refresh.php"); ?>  ` and after 10secs your noti_refresh.php will be loaded on your `ul`

Comment: A dirty fix is to load the contents to only the first `<li class="ref">` element like  `$('.ref:first').load('inc/noti_refresh.php').hide().fadeIn(3000);`

Comment: thank you all i'v resolved the issued by answering my own question, as below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by removing the `<?php include('notif_refresh.php');` 
and instead i just used these two functions

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ref').load('inc/noti_refresh.php');
});

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Load_external_content()
{

  $('.ref').load('inc/noti_refresh.php').hide().fadeIn(3000);

}
setInterval('Load_external_content()', 10000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you load the content into `.dropdown-menu` instead of into `.ref`?